# Can i move the second exists to the left in this formula?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Is it legal to change

$\exists$x A(x) $\implies$ $\exists$y B(y)

to:

$\exists$x $\exists$y (A(x) $\implies$  B(y))

If i'm thinking correctly, A(x) is free from $\exists$y and should be allowed to move. However i am not able to prove it. So far i have:

$\neg$$\exists$x A(x) $\vee$ $\exists$y B(y)

$\forall$x $\neg$A(x) $\vee$ $\exists$y B(y)

$\forall$x $\neg$A(x) $\vee$ $\neg$$\forall$y $\neg$B(y)

$\forall$x ($\neg$A(x) $\vee$ $\neg$$\forall$y $\neg$B(y))

$\forall$x $\neg$ $\forall$y($\neg$A(x) $\vee$ $\neg$B(y))

$\neg$$\exists$x $\forall$y($\neg$A(x) $\vee$ $\neg$B(y))

$\neg$$\exists$x $\forall$y(A(x) $\wedge$ B(y))

$\neg$$\exists$x $\neg$$\exists$y $\neg$(A(x) $\wedge$ B(y))

$\neg$$\exists$x $\neg$$\exists$y ($\neg$A(x) $\vee$ $\neg$B(y))

$\neg$$\exists$x $\neg$$\exists$y (A(x) $\implies$ $\neg$ B(y))

I'm likely to have mistakes here, have not touched this in a while.

Comment: Absolutely not. There are no free variables in $\exists xA(x)\to \exists y B(y)$, but there are free variables in $\exists x\exists y A(x) \to B(y)$. It may be that you forgot parentheses. If that's the case, please include them.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean with change? It's possible that the second formula can be derived from the first, but not the other way around. In this case would it be legal?

Comment: Yes there were missing parenthesis, i am trying to simplify another formula that contains something similar to ∃()→∃() within a for all.

Comment: See also [Conversion to prenex form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conversion_to_prenex_form) : converting the leftmost quantifier we get the equivalent : $\forall x (Ax \to \exists y By)$. Then we can move the rightmost to get $\forall x  \exists y (Ax \to  By)$

Comment: Thank you, that clearly answered my question! I had the rules written down however i guess i was not that comfortable with them yet.